# automatically detect date format from string in linux?

Tags: bash, shell, date, time

I have a date `20190620_113859` which is from `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
Is it possible to detect that `+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S` format from `20190620_113859` as input
like

```
$ date --detect-format '20190620_113859'
%Y%m%d_%H%M%S
```

Comment: There is no straightforward to do this without doing an explicit character by character match.

Comment: Since there's an overlap between the months and the first 12 days, 12 hours, etc., there is no easy way to detect what a timestamp format string should be. Even just the short string `242424` wouldn't be able to be accurately deciphered into a format since `%Y%m`, `%H%M%S`, `%M%Y` (and many others) would all be "correct".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even `date` can't parse that format, so even if there were such an option, it couldn't help:

```
% date --debug -d 20190620_113859
date: parsed number part: (Y-M-D) 2019-06-20
date: error: parsing failed, stopped at '113859'
date: invalid date ‘20190620_113859’
```